# Disadvantages of using ternary operator

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the following statments in my source code

```
int tableField1;
int tableField2;

int propertyField1;
int propertyField2;

if (tableField1 != null)
{
  propertyField1 = tableField1;
}

if (tableField2 != null)
{
  propertyField2 = tableField1;
}

// the above pattern is repeated for 10 tablefields ie tableField3, tableField4... tableField10
```

I reduced the above statments using the ternary operator as follows

```
propertyField1 = tableField1 != null ? tableField1 : propertyField1;
propertyField2 = tableField2 != null ? tableField2 : propertyField2;
```

Following are my questions:

1) Is ternary operator inefficient to use than the if statements.

2) What are the disadvantages (if any) to use ternary operator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use the null coalescing operator instead?

```
propertyField1 = tableField1 ?? propertyField1;
```

Admittedly it looks *slightly* odd assigning the original value back to the same variable. It's possible that it'll be very slightly less efficient than the `if` statements, as in theory you're reading the value and assigning it again... but I wouldn't be surprised if the JIT elided that. Anyway, that's definitely at the level of micro-optimization.

Some people consider the conditional operator to be bad for readability - I generally think it's fine for simple statements like this, although it *is* somewhat obscuring the meaning of "only change the value if we've got a new one".

Comment: Thank you Jon. I wasn't aware about null coalescing.

Answer (score 3):

1) No, the compiler will (should) treat the ternary operator in exactly the same manner as an explicit `if` statement, so there is no difference in efficiency.

2) The only disadvantage is that it can make your code harder to read. On the other hand, it's more concise. Generally avoid ternary statements for readability reasons, except for very simple cases. This probably counts as a very simple case.

I claim this answer is more language-agnostic than Jon Skeet's :)

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of point 1. The if statement version *only* has an assignment to `propertyField1` when `tableField1` is null. Otherwise there's no way the value gets changed. Logically speaking, the conditional operator version will *always* assign to `propertyField1`, possibly after reading the same field. Imagine another thread is messing with the values - it could assign a new value to `propertyField1` *after* the read but *before* the assignment. That write could then effectively be lost. That's not possible with the `if` version.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, assignment is very cheap so unless this is in a tight loop it's not going to make a lot of difference. I've also assumed a single-threaded system. I don't claim that my answer is more *correct* than yours :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, the ternary statement is mostly just syntactic sugar, though the compiler can optimize for it.

In this case, I believe it would probably be more efficient, though I'd guess that the compiler would optimize it to be about the same as an if statement.

Disadvantages? Well, it might be harder to read in some cases. It depends on what you're going after.