# How to style div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

```
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <div class="block" id="${item.id}" style="background: black"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

Is it possible style div depends on current `item.id` avoiding jsp `<c:choose>  <c:when test="${ item.num == 0}">` inside div when first load the page?

`item.num` can be 1 or 0.

Need something like this:

```
 if(item.num==0){
    style="background: black"
    }else{
    style="background: transparant"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use the ternary operator? No need for jQuery here...

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <div class="block" id="${item.id}" style="background: ${item.num==0?'black':'white'}"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

### Update

If you want to do it correctly, try to avoid inline styles and add a css class instead. So you can define your styles easily in a separate file.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <div class="block block-${item.num==0?'black':'white'}" id="${item.id}"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

And the corresponding css file.

```
/** myApp.css */
.block-black {
    background: black;
}
.block-white {
    background: white;
}
```

### Update 2

Another solution could be to save result to variable.

```
<%-- save result to variable (${itemBackground}) for better reusability -->
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <c:set var="itemBackground" value="${item.num==0?'black':'white'}">
    <div class="block ${itemBackground}" id="${item.id}"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i think it is better decision!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but if your `item.id` is in numerical format then it is advisable to append a string to it Eg: `"id=list_"{item.id}` because some browsers have some issues dealing with id which starts with a number

Now once all the `div` are assigned with a unique id you can style any individual. Suppose you want to style the div with item.id = 123 then you can use below script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list_123").css("background-color","red");
});
```

**EDIT:** You can create a new data attribute in your dynamically generated div as,

```
<div class="block" id="list_"${item.id} style="background: black" data-num=${item.num}>
```

Now from your jQuery you can iterate through all the div with `class=block` and find those `data-num` attribute which has the value 0 as,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.block').each(function(i, obj) {
        if($(this).attr("data-num")=="0"){
            $(this).css("background-color","black");
        }
    });
});
```

[**Here is a working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9kxobdk5/)

Comment: I need to check item.num when i first load the page and depends on the number show background: black or background: transparant respectivly.

Comment: @RuslanLomov By item.num you mean the index of you items that are generated ?

Comment: i think yes.Thx alot!Didn't know about new data attribute btw

Comment: There is no need to do this on client site by adding a bunch of JS.

Comment: @gearsdigital your approach looks good in case there is only one attribute to update, but if there are multiple properties to update then the ternary operators becomes difficult to maintain and damages readability as describes here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149530/disadvantages-of-using-ternary-operator

Comment: Yes, i know, but that was not OPs question. If you have multiple attributes to update, you can save your ternary result to a variable and use this instead. See my update #2

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about CSS?

```
.block:nth-child(odd) { 
    background-color:#black; 
}
.block:nth-child(even) { 
    background-color:transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want if you only want to effect only the one div with an ID of 0. You will also need to prefix it with a string.

```
$('#item-0').css('background', 'black');
```

You can also pass an object of styles like this:

```
$('#item-0').css({
  background: 'black',
  color: 'white'
});
```

However if it's always going to be the first one I would suggest using plain CSS.

```
#item-0 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: What about id in div?